# Is nodejs fs.WriteStream.write(chunk) "atomic" wrt async events?

Tags: node.js

Suppose I write the following node.js code (for some imaginary event `data` coming in from the network):

```js
const file = fs.createWriteStream('my_file');
network.on('data', (data) => {
  file.write(SOME_DELIMITER + data);
});
```

If `data` is very large and comes in very quickly, can I still guarantee that each chunk will be continguous and separated from the others in the file? I don't need them to be correctly ordered, but I do need them to each be intact. Or is it possible for a race condition to happen and for data to be interleaved? If so, what's the best/most performant way to get what I want here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity: yes; my understanding now is that `WriteStream.write` is actually synchronous and so no race conditions can occur.